# Which harmonic numbers have prime numerators?

Tags: number-theory, fractions, harmonic-numbers

Let
$$1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1n=\frac{q}{p}$$
with $(p,q)=1$ and $q$ is a prime number.

(I) Prove or disprove that the quantity of $n$ is limited.

(II) Determine all $n$ satisfying the condition.

I use the matlab and get some $n$ meeted the condition:$2,3,5,8,9,21,26,41,56,62,69,79,89,91,122,127,143,167,201,230,247,252,290,349,376,459,489,492,516,662,687,714,771,932,944,1061,1281,1352,1489,1730, 1969,2012,2116,2457,2663,2955,3083,3130,3204,3359,3494,3572,...$

Comment: @Surb The harmonic series diverges but for any exact N $\Sigma^{N}_{k=1}{\frac{1}{k}}$ is bounded

Comment: The fact that there are quite a bunch of valid $n$ (and the corresponding $q$ are getting enormous), does not seem to support the claim of (I) that there are only finitely many such $n$ ...

Comment: Was this an assigned exercise? If you are making up the problem yourself, then why do you think (I) is true? As Hagen von Eitzen points out, the numerical evidence is not in your favor.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Actually,when n=81658 the numerators is a prime with 35479 digts

Comment: @Xiaolang: So why is problem (I) posed at all? There is no evidence suggesting it is true.

Comment: A friend of mine claims that all of the $n$ less than ${13}^{25}$ and he said "p-adic" @KCd

Comment: In that case just ask your friend to explain it to you! (I think there's either a misunderstanding or your friend is making a joke at your expense when a bound like $13^{25}$ is being thrown around.)

Comment: This is sequence A056903 in the OEIS (http://oeis.org/A056903).  Probably the sequence is infinite but there's no known technique that would prove such a thing.

Comment: According to http://oeis.org/A056903, the sequence includes $56$, not $59$.

Comment: What is meant by $(p,q)=1$?

Comment: @RobertJørgensgaardEngdahl that the greatest common divisor of $p$ and $q$ is $1$.

Comment: I checked up on the discrepancy mentioned by @r.e.s. above. $56$ is in the sequence and $59$ isn't, so I corrected the post.

Answer (score 1):

As a partial answer, see Wolstenholme’s theorem: for a prime $p > 3$, the numerator of $H_{p-1}$ is divisible by $p^2$, where

$$
H_{p-1} \equiv \sum_{n=1}^{p-1} \frac{1}{n}
$$