# Consecutive prime numerators of harmonic numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, harmonic-numbers

Let

$$\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}=\frac{a}{b}$$

and let $a$ and $b$ are coprime, $h_{n}=a$.

$h_{n}$ is prime [for](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854427/which-harmonic-numbers-have-prime-numerators)

$$n=2,3,5,8,9,21,26,41,56,62,69,79,89,91,122,127,143,167,201,230,247,252,290,349,376,459,489,492,516,662,687,714,771,932,944,1061,1281,1352,1489,1730, 1969,2012,2116,2457,2663,2955,3083,3130,3204,3359,3494,3572,3995,4155,4231,4250,4496,4616,5069,5988,6656,6883,8067,8156,8661,9097,\ldots$$

I guess proving that there are infinitely (or finitely) many primes of the form $h_n$ is very hard. But can we prove both of the $h_n$ and $h_{n+1}$ cannot be prime for $n>8$?

Comment: What sort of question is this? I think it isn't trivial. Where is the conjecture from, just looking on the numbers or are there reasons why it should be right?

Comment: Just for reference, the first values of $h_n$ are listed here: https://oeis.org/A001008

Comment: I edited the question to include some more values for $n$, more than oeis.org, which for some reason only includes values up to $3572$

Comment: @vrugtehagel  : what do you already know about the numerators of the harmonic numbers ?

Comment: I haven't looked much into it before. The only thing I've done on this subject is prove that the harmonic series is never an integer for $n>1$. But this is interesting, so I'll definitely look into it

Comment: @vrugtehagel Did you look in https://oeis.org/A056903/b056903.txt ? They call it a "b-file" and it goes up to $h_{97} = 78128$.

Comment: @Mr. Brooks, no, thank you. That is be some *very* useful information

Comment: @vrugtehagel You're welcome.