# Harmonic Numbers' Numerators Divisible by a Prime $p$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science

For a prime $p$, I am trying to determine the set of all $n$ for which the numerator of $H_n$ is divisible by $p$, with $H_n$ being the $n$'th harmonic number.

After going through a lot of literature, this turns out to be a difficult thing to do. The most promising paper regarding my question seems to be [this paper by David W. Boyd](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/experimental-mathematics/volume-3/issue-4/A-p-adic-study-of-the-partial-sums-of-the/em/1048515811.full). (PDFs easily accessible over the internet). Because the problem is difficult, I am trying to focus on primes $p<550$ as suggested by the paper.

Using similiar notation to the paper, let $J_p$ be the set of those $n$ for which the numerator of $H_n$ is divisible by $p$. They give in the paper:

$J_3= \{2,7,22\}$

$J_5= \{4,20,24\}$

And I ran a computer program for quite some time to find:

$J_7 = \{6,42,48,295,299,337,341,2096,2390,14675,16731,16735,102728...\}$

But I don't know if that's a complete list. EDIT: this turns out to be a complete list

I believe this is the core of their technique / algorithm:

[image]

Similiarly define, for a given $p$:

$G_m=\{p^{m-1}\leq n < p^m : p \mid H_n\} \quad  G_0=\{0\}$

Because it is known that $p \mid H_{p-1}$, it must be that $p-1 \in G_1$

But I don't understand the next formulas that follow in the paper: $H_n=ap + O(p^2) , \quad H_{pn+k} = a + H_k + O(p) , \quad a + H_k = O(p)$

Does it mean that given the other parameters in the RHS of the equation, I can get the LHS in $O(p)$ time? Also, what is the variable $a$ exactly? It's not mentioned in the paper beforehand. How do I find it?

Looking at the values in the given $J_p$, it seems the solutions come in "subsets", so that solutions in subset $s_{i+1} \in S_{i+1}$ are formed from solutions $s \in S_i$ such that every $ps \leq s_{i+1} < ps + p$ for some $s$. For example, looking at $J_7$, then $42$ can generate solutions in the range $[7\cdot 42 , 7 \cdot 42 + 7]=[294,301]$, similiarly $48$ generates solutions in the range $[7\cdot 48 , 7 \cdot 48 + 7]=[336,343]$. And they both generate $2$ solutions each. This means I would only need to check divisibility of numerators in a small range (assuming $p$ is small), resulting in $O(mp)$ algorithm, with $m$ defined as above.

Is that observation correct? I think it is similiar to how they define $G_m$. But How can I quickly obtain $H_n$ mod $p$ for some $n$ using previous values? Only a few values need to be checked, but as $m$ grows, the numerators become extremely large, about $p^m$.

Another paper I found gives a more detailed example of the technique: [p-Integral harmonic sums](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82783823.pdf)

Answers regarding any of my questions will be great. The best answer I can hope for is an explanation of their technique, what they do exactly and how they do it. A sketch for their technique revolving around $J_7$ as an example would be great, going through each of the $m$'s before $G_m$ becomes empty.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A229493 – you have the full list for $p=7$. See also the links to post-Boyd literature givem there, and also https://oeis.org/A092103 which gives the size of $J_p$ for various $p$.

Comment: Also worth a look: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854427/which-harmonic-numbers-have-prime-numerators

Comment: Had a look at those links?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Hey Gerry, thank you. Indeed I have. The Boyd paper is the one I had read before I posted this question, (gave a link to it too), which does give a method, but I do not understand it fully. Hence I posted this question, trying to get a more thorough explanation.